# Relimit pyplot.psd y-axis plot based on frequency range

Tags: python, matplotlib, psd

So I'm trying to find the `psd` of various signals sampled at different frequencies and compare them in the 0-50Hz range

I have this code:

```
for i, th in enumerate(ths): 
    NFFT = 2**(int(np.log2(th.size)) - 8)
    ax.psd(th, Fs = freq[i], NFFT = NFFT, scale_by_freq = False)
ax.set_xlabel("freq (Hz)")
ax.set_xlim(0,50)
#ax.relim()              #These
#ax.autoscale()          #Didn't work
```

What I am trying to do:

Since the signals are low-pass filtered below 50Hz, any signal with a sampling frequency higher than 100Hz has a part that drops to very low psd.  So my `ylim` are very large, and the part of the `psd` I want to see is not easily visible.  I can manually `set_ylim` every time I call the function, but I'd like some way to automatically set `ylim` to fit the `psd`, however every manual method I've found on SO assumes I know the y-values already.  But `psd` does a lot of calculations on the backend that I don't know how to access.

Is there any way to either:

1. read the y-values out of a `psd` plot to an array, or
2. somehow refit the y-axis based on the current x-axis in `pyplot`?

Comment: Can you use the return values of [`psd`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.psd.html)? It returns `Pxx` (1d array), `freq` (1d array), and `line` (`Line2D`).

Comment: @WilliamMiller Ahh, that works.  Didn't notice it outputs arrays natively.

Comment: Figured I’d make it into an answer then - glad it helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the return values of [`matplotlib.pyplot.psd`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.psd.html).  It returns

- `Pxx` (1D array) - The values for the power spectrum `P_{xx}` before scaling (real valued)
- `freq` (1D array) - The frequencies corresponding to the elements in *Pxx*.
- `line` (`Line2D`) - The line created by this function. Only returned if *return_line* is `True`.

In this case I believe the frequency values could be used to programmatically set the y-limits appropriately, like this:

```
mx = []; mn = []
for i, th in enumerate(ths): 
    NFFT = 2**(int(np.log2(th.size)) - 8)
    val, freqs = ax.psd(th, Fs = freq[i], NFFT = NFFT, scale_by_freq = False)
    mx.append(val[freqs <= 50].max())
    mn.append(val[freqs <= 50].min())
ax.set_xlabel("freq (Hz)")
ax.set_xlim(0,50)
ax.set_ylim(np.rint(10 * np.log10(np.array(mn).min())) - 2, 
            np.rint(10 * np.log10(np.array(mx).max())) + 2 )
```